# Show / Hide product tab using if statement in local.xml Magento 1.9 CE

Tags: php, xml, magento, product, magento-1.9

I'm fairly new to magento, using CE 1.9.

I know how to remove / add tabs on the product page via local.xml
However I'm trying to hide/show a tab based on the value of an attribute of the product.

I have created a custom tab successfully. Additionally the customTab.phtml file I created I was able to get an if statement to work successfully... sort of...

Here is my code inside the phtml file:

```
    <?php
    $staticBlockId = 'block_product_tab2';
    $product = Mage::registry('current_product'); ?>

<?php   if($product->getRepairservice()): ?>
            <div class="std"><?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId($staticBlockId)->toHtml(); ?></div>

<?php   endif; ?>
```

This will successfully hide or show "content" of the tab based on the boolean value of the attribute. However it still is showing the tab, it's just empty.

So I'm thinking I need to go to where it's created in local.xml but I'm not sure how to structure the if statement or get access to the attribute. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most clear way of doing this is by creating your own layout handle, see: http://inchoo.net/magento/custom-layout-update-handles/. There you've to check if you're on a product page and then check your `getRepairservice()`, for example:

```
// Inside the controllerActionLayoutLoadBefore() function of Inchoo's example
$layout = $observer->getEvent()->getLayout();
$product = Mage::registry('current_product');

if($product && $product->getRepairservice())
{
    $layout->getUpdate()->addHandle('REPAIR_SERVICE')
}
```

After that you can add your tab nicely with XML.

```
<REPAIR_SERVICE>
    <reference name="product.info">
        <block type="catalog/product_view_description" name="product.new.tab" as="new.tab" template="catalog/product/view/mynewcustomtab.phtml">
            <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
            <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Custom Tab</value></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</REPAIR_SERVICE>
```